# Javascript dialog is programmed to move when the page scrolls, but it flickers. Can this be fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I've written some jQuery code to display a box with data in the corner of the users' web browser.  I'm using the `.scroll` event to make the box stay in the corner as the user scrolls up and down the page.  Let me emphasize that **I am not using jquery-ui dialog**.

The only problem is that the box flickers as the page scrolls.  I'm afraid that there will be no cross-browser solution to this problem as the different browsers seem to behave differently with scrolling.  Barring a cross-browser solution, an IE solution would be nice (My web application is designed to be used by a specific group of about 100 users in my organization.)

Here are snippets of the relative code:

```
ExternalScroll: function () {
            LittleBlackBook.setPosition();
        }

    setPosition: function () {
        var scrollPosition = $(self).scrollTop();
        var cssTop = LittleBlackBookStatic.determineCssTop(this.height, this.isTop, this.vOffset, scrollPosition);
        var cssHeight = LittleBlackBookStatic.determineCssHeight(this.height);
        var cssLeft = LittleBlackBookStatic.determineCssLeft(this.width, this.isLeft, this.hOffset);
        var cssWidth = LittleBlackBookStatic.determineCssWidth(this.width);
        this.jQueryObj.css('top', cssTop);
        this.jQueryObj.css('height', cssHeight);
        this.jQueryObj.css('left', cssLeft);
        this.jQueryObj.css('width', cssWidth);
    }

var LittleBlackBookStatic = {
    determineCssTop: function (height, isTop, vOffset, vScroll) {
        var windowHeight = $(self).height();
        var scrollPosition = $(self).scrollTop();
        var newModalTop = isTop ? vOffset + vScroll : windowHeight - height + vScroll - vOffset;
        return newModalTop + 'px';
    },

    determineCssHeight: function (height) {
        return height + 'px';
    },

    determineCssLeft: function (width, isLeft, hOffset) {
        var windowWidth = $(self).width();
        var newModalLeft = isLeft ? hOffset : windowWidth - width - hOffset;
        return newModalLeft + 'px';
    },

    determineCssWidth: function (width) {
        return width + 'px';
    }
} // end LittleBlackBookStatic
```

I'm using jQuery to look up the scroll position as the page scrolls and change the CSS.

Is there a better way; a way that will make it scroll without flickering?  If no, then why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `fixed` positioning for that box instead instead of animating it to keep it in the corner.

You'll use less javascript and avoid flickering that comes with animation.